# Is it possible to change the color of a line or rectangle in fxml with scenebuilder?

Tags: javafx, colors, scenebuilder

I'm doing a project where i need a line to change color when it's clicked but i can't figure out how to do it; i tried this (with A2B2 is the name of the line in the code)

```
@FXML void clickA2B2() {
        A2B2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff0000");
```

in the fxml controller but didn't work, and since you can't seem to use ActionEvent to a line i was wondering if there was a solution for it 
code of the fxml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<Pane centerShape="false" minHeight="180.0" prefWidth="320.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.InterfaceController">
   <children>
      <Rectangle fx:id="B2" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" fill="#e9faff" height="19.0" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="10.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" width="19.0">
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
         </cursor>
      </Rectangle>
 <Line fx:id="A2B2" cache="true" cacheHint="SPEED" endX="-82.0" fill="RED" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="9.0" onMouseClicked="#mouseoverB2" startX="-96.0" strokeWidth="2.0">
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor>
      </Line>
```

and there is the controller code

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;


public class InterfaceController {
        @FXML Line A2B2;
        @FXML void mouseoverB2() {  
        A2B2.getStyleClass().add("B2wa");}
```

with the css :

```
 .B2wa{
        -fx-background-color:#90EE90 }
```

and the main :

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane root = (Pane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Interface.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Line` doesn't have an `onAction` property (see [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Line.html). It does, of course, inherit all the event handler properties from `Node` (also listed in those docs).

Comment: @James_D `@FXML void mouseoverB2() {
A2B2.getStyleClass().add("B2wa");}`
with the CSS 
`.B2wa{
        -fx-background-color:#90EE90 }`
does it works like that or am i doing something wrong now?

Comment: Either that or the method you posted in your question are fine. You just need to associate them with an existing handler property in the FXML.

Comment: @James_D well i added the method to the line in scenebuilder under the "on mouse clicked" but it still don't work when i click on it so i don't really know how to do it but thanks to your answers so far !

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @James_D I just edited the post, thank you for your time !

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra what is wrong with it here? sorry i'm new to this :/

Comment: The example doesn't run as posted (there are parts of some of the files missing, e.g. the FXML has two elements not closed, and the controller has a missing `}`). But anyway, a [`Line`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#line) doesn't have a `-fx-background-color` property. Use `-fx-fill`, or `-fx-stroke`, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @James_D sorry the code in itself is quite long and very repetitive since there's a lot of lines and rectangles, I just want it to change color when i click on it, and i tried -fx-fill and then put it under the "on mouse clicked" in scenebuilder but still doesn't do anything :/

Comment: Depending on how your line is configured (i.e. width and stroke width), you might not be able to see the fill. Assuming stroke width is not zero, you should always be able to see the stroke.

Comment: @James_D my bad ! I put `-fx-stroke-color` instead of `-fx-stroke` so it didn't worked ! sorry for losing your time and ty again for the help you provided !